# No audio with openmeeting sip call

Tags: sip, openmeetings

I am making a setup with openmeeting server on ubuntu and soft-phone phonerlite on windows.

Configurations are made as per below link 
http://openmeetings.apache.org/red5sip-integration_3.1.html

I observe call being active on phonerlite on making a sip call to conference room , but on logging into conference room on openmeeting server I observe no audio.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: What OM version are you using? Are there any errors in openmeetings.log? Can you connect to the same room using another phonerlite and can can these 2 phonerlites hear each other?

Comment: Thanks for the response.      I am using OM version 3.2.1 (red5321). I see no errors in logs . Two sip clients can login to conference room and talk. But, if I try to call a sip client from conference room(SIP dial pad) call is landing onto client (soft phone - phonerlite). On receiving the call  I listen only a music (which is heard during call-hold is audible , no audio is heard). I suspect some configuration in extension.conf of asterisk needs to be done , but not sure. Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: Can you also check red5sip logs? this is the tool perfoming "intercommunication". I'll try to set up local asterisk and double-check everything next week

Comment: I didn't get how to collect red5sip logs , but below are the logs in asterisk

Comment: OK, it seems latest red5sip is not compatible with OM 3.2.1, will try to fix it ASAP, will report back here

Comment: Thanks very much ....will be waiting for the fix ...:-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems latest red5sip is not compatible with OM 3.2.1 [1] :(

Could you please check if latest nightly build [2] will work for you with latest red5sip [3]

Latest documentation is available here [4] (will be on the main site after release)

Please let me know if anything else remain broken

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENMEETINGS-1664

[2] https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/Openmeetings%203.3.x/

[3] https://github.com/openmeetings/red5sip

[4] https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/Openmeetings%203.3.x/site/openmeetings-server/red5sip-integration_3.3.html

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the given openmeeting 3.3.1 build. 
Things I observed are:

1. Call from sip client(Zoiper) to Conference room have established without audio problems. Didn't get intimation in conference room about call.
2. Call from conference room to sip client(Zoiper) can't be established. It is not showing any status in openmeetings Conference room. Even it is not giving any log in asterisk client.

I suspect that we need to change something in extensions.conf given in https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/Openmeetings%203.3.x/site/openmeetings-server/red5sip-integration_3.3.html to make outward call from openmeetings room to sip client.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "Didn't get intimation in conference room about call."? No notification on new user?    2. You are right, additional configuration in asterisk configs is required

Comment: When SIP client make call to conference room the call was established properly, but in conference room I didn't get any prompt.

Comment: Can you tell what should be changed in extensions.conf to make call from conference room

Comment: Actually the only thing changed on room connect is XX in "SIP Transport (XX)" user name.     Unfortunately I'm not an expert in Asterisk configuration. I just make it work with OpenMeetings :)

Comment: I didn't get what changes you made. What did you mean by - XX in "SIP Transport (XX)" user name. Please elaborate on this.

Comment: I didn't made any changes. By design "SIP Transport" user displays the number of connected SIP users in it's last name as (XX) where XX == number of SIP users. i.e. "SIP Transport (1)" means there 1 sip user